# Concurrent Read & Write implementation strategy on database | Memtables

Tags: database-design, concurrency, cassandra, rocksdb

I am doing research on how databases are designed internally. I found that there are three main components

1. WAL - Write ahead log
2. Memtable - In-memory data structure say RedBlack Tree or SkipList
3. SSTables - Files on the disk

Now consider a database like `cassandra`, it has sequential writes so there are no issues in updating the `memtable`. However suppose if a `write` and `read` are coming at the same time then how does database like `cassandra` works.

I am asking this because - suppose database is using the `ReadBlack` tree as memtable and it starts `write` which may cause the tree restructuring but at the same time `read` is also happening then its can cause inconsistencies.

Another case, suppose if database is getting the `lock` on `redblacktree` before any write then it would be huge performance degradation as there could be 1000s of read waiting for the lock to release.

Can someone help with on how does it work,

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntIntro.html

Answer (score 0):

That's not really relevant because Cassandra does not use a locking mechanism (with the exception of lightweight transactions) so writes are non-blocking which is part of the reason they are really fast.

The mutations are persisted to the commitlog by appending which means there are no disk seeks or sorting/ordering involved.

Cassandra really is designed for high velocity throughput that supports reads/writes at internet scale. This is just one of the reasons tech giants who are household names choose Cassandra for their demanding workloads. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

RocksDB uses [a skip list capable of lock-free simultaneous read and write](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/main/memtable/inlineskiplist.h). Because of the invariants of the structure, individual entries cannot be reclaimed, so Deletes have to use tombstones, and an entire skip list is reclaimed after it is flushed to an SST file.

More about WAL in RocksDB write path:
https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/WAL-Performance
https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Pipelined-Write
https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/unordered_write